# Deleting data using checkbox in PHP

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with deleting data using checkbox.
I actually, retrieve all the records that I want to show/display.
But the Delete button doesn't work.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM admin";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

<?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='".$rows['id']."'/>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $rows['username'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $rows['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
?>

<input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
```

Here's the IF STATEMENT to check if the delete button was active.

```
if($delete){
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM admin WHERE id='$del_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
    // if successful redirect to delete_multiple.php 
    if($result){
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=delete_admin.php\">";
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is $count? What is $checkbox? How are you outputting the checkboxes? You'll need to show more of your code...

Comment: do not use mysql_ functions use PDO or mysqli_ instead

Comment: Hi Mr. White, I already update the my question. Sorry for giving incomplete details

Comment: Please post the whole code of both (the input and delete), the fault can be everywhere.

Comment: try this
if(isset($_post['delete'])){
//do something here
}

Comment: I hope you defined `$delete` as `$_POST['delete']` and `$checkbox` as `$_POST['check']`. Right?

Comment: <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
also put this code in between php tags

Comment: Your code is **very** open to SQL injection. Someone could literally delete all rows from `admin` simply by changing the checkbox value to `' OR 1 = 1 --`. Use PDO or mysqli_ with prepared statements and bind your variables.

Comment: That's all the code in my php file. I don't think that It would be appropriate to post all my HTML code here. That's only the PHP syntax in my PHP file

Comment: Hello Lockdown, I already put inside PHP tag.

Comment: I try this one also, `code`if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
     foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $del_id){
         $del_id = (int)$del_id;
         $sql = "DELETE FROM admin WHERE `id` = $del_id"; 
         mysql_query($sql);
     }
     header('Location: admin_page.php');
 }
 mysql_close();
 ?> `code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try do it:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']) { //check if you received the post

    for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['check']); $i++) { // count the elements

        $del_id = $_POST['check'][$i];

...
```

Comment: I don't know how to mark this thread as RESOLVED. Thank you so much Guilherme

Answer (score 1):

You can `IN` function of MySql

```
if($delete){
    $checkboxIds = implode(',',$_POST['checkbox']);

    $sql = "DELETE FROM admin WHERE id IN ('".$checkboxIds."')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    // if successful redirect to delete_multiple.php 
    if($result){
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=delete_admin.php\">";
    }
}
```

Comment: While that's true, I believe it's not solving the problem. It should be suggested in a comment. Good approach however ;)